# Setting PATH vs. exporting PATH in ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, profile

What's the difference and which is better to use when customizing my bash profile? Documentation on the `export` command is scarce, as it's a builtin cmd.

Excerpt from version 1 of my ~/.bash_profile:

```
#PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin

#add Homebrew’s sbin to PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Output from: `echo $PATH`
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/njboot/bin`

Excerpt from version 2:

```
#PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin

#add Homebrew’s sbin to PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Output from `echo $PATH` is the same as in version 1. `env` is the same as well.

So:

- 1) What's the benefit of using `export` vs. setting PATH explicitly?
- 2) Is there any functional difference between version 1 and version 2 when applied?
- 3) Which should I use and why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your questions specifically:

1. `export` *does* set the `$PATH` explicitly.
2. No. `export` sets environment for child processes, but `$PATH` is already set for the current environment. So, in the second example, when the command is read-in - and *before* `export` is executed - the current environment's value for `$PATH` is expanded into the `$PATH` word.
3. You should use whichever is necessary and/or comfortable for you. Neither makes any difference functionally, so this is primarily a question of style.

POSIX defines the [`export` builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) so:

> The shell shall give the `export` attribute to the variables corresponding to the specified names, which shall cause them to be in the environment of subsequently executed commands. If the name of a variable is followed by *= word*, then the value of that variable shall be set to *word*.

From another of my [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137707/52934):

*There is little difference between declaring a shell variable and an environment variable. Because export is a builtin it declares an environment variable for the process next invoked, but if you don't invoke one that process remains the shell, and so your variable is twice evaluated.*

You can remove all exports without any effect at all on exported variables so long as you don't use `export` to twice evaluate. By twice evaluate I mean:

```
var1=var2 
export "${var1}=var3"
echo "$var2"
var3
```

Instead just use:

```
set -a
```

...at the top of the script. All variables defined thereafter will be automatically `exported` - which would include variables you might not have previously `export`ed. Alternatively you could only `set -a` for a portion of the script and later `set +a` to unset it - it could also work as function.

But subshells automatically inherit variable values anyway, so:

```
var1=value
( echo "$(echo "$var1")" )
value
```

`export` makes no difference in that case.

But if your script calls another script, or any other executable that interprets values you've `export`ed and you cease to `export` them, then those values will no longer be available in their environment. In the following example I use the shell variable `$PS1` - which defines the contents of an interactive shell's prompt - to demonstrate how variations on `export`ed variables affect child processes.

```
export PS1="$(printf "this is another executable\n > ")"
echo exit | sh -i

###OUTPUT###

this is another executable
 > exit
exit
```

But ...

```
PS1="$(printf "this is another executable\n > ")"
echo exit | sh -i

###OUTPUT###

sh-4.3$ exit
exit
```

But then again, if you explicitly declare environment variables while invoking a process...

```
PS1="$(printf "this is another executable\n > ")"
{
echo exit | PS1=$PS1 sh -i
echo exit | sh -i
}

###OUTPUT###

this is another executable
 > exit
exit
sh-4.3$ exit
exit
```

Any of the `ENV` files first invoked by a shell such as `.bashrc` or `.profile` will set variable values for the life of that shell. So any variables that are set and `export`ed within those files will maintain that `export` characteristic and be `export`ed to all child processes invoked by that shell for the life of the shell or until they are `unset`.

It is notable, though, that `bash` extends the `export` builtin somewhat to include the `-n` option - which enables you to remove the `export` attribute from a variable without `unset`ting it, but this is not portable behavior.

Answer (score 17):

[Here's a similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/153371/what-does-export-do-in-bash).

A short answer:

https://superuser.com/a/153378/333431

> Exported variables get passed on to child processes, not-exported
>   variables do not.

This means you should `export` your variables, if you intend to use them in subshells.

You can test this:

```
$ TEST="im_not_here"
$ echo $TEST
im_not_here
$ bash -c 'echo $TEST'
<empty output>
$ export TEST2="im_here"
$ echo $TEST2
im_here
$ bash -c 'echo $TEST2'
im_here
```

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by *subshells*. `var=val ; (echo $var)` still yields `val`.

Comment: And yet `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` would work equally well without the `export`: once a variable is exported, it stays exported, and further assignments modify the environment variable. Furthermore, to clarify mikeserv's comment, you don't need `export` to use variables in subshells, you need them to use them in child programs. *Subshell* is a technical term, meaning a `fork`ed copy of the running shell. `(echo $var)` runs `echo `$var` in a subshell and sees the original shell's internal variable; `sh -c 'echo $var'` runs `echo $var` in a child program and only sees environment variables.